# Long python imports style (staying beneath 80 chars) with many submodules

Tags: python, import, styles, pep8

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273847/long-imports-in-python), we know how to import something like

```
from asdfasdfasdfsdf import somethingthathisverylongandbreaksthepepstandards
# Should be
from asdfasdfasdfsdf import (
    somethingthathisverylongandbreaksthepepstandards)
```

How do we deal with the following situation?

```
from this.is.a.long.sequence.of.nested.folders.we.cant.break.up import a
```

If we use the backslash in the middle of this, I'm not sure if it is the most pythonic/most stylish solution. How should I approach this to keep PEP8?

Comment: Is `this.is....` a module of yours, or a 3rd party module? Because if it's one of your, then I'd suggest that you consider creating a convenience import of `a` in a package on a higher level, so that you can do e.g.  `from this.is.a.long import a`, but still keep your deeply nested package structure on the file system for code organization.

Comment: Yeah that is the case, it is one of my modules

Comment: Then I would suggest you go with such a convenience import in a module where it makes sense for your package. For example, in `this/is/a/long/__init__.py` do `from .sequence.of.nested.folders.we.cant.break.up import a`. You can then simply use `from this.is.a.long import a` in the rest of your code.