# Linting: Very long imports in Python

Tags: python, pylint

Pylint complains about my super long imports in Python.

```
from a.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.very.long.path.to.module import func
```

The problem is, everyhing before `import` is already over 80 characters, so [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273847/long-imports-in-python) doesn't really apply.

Is there a way to line-break this such that each line is shorter than 80 characters?

Comment: Just run it through black. If pylint still complains, ignore pylint.

Comment: @wim , I got black v19.3b0 and was not able to reduce it to less than 95 chars for the first line. Still upvoted your comment tho : p

Comment: @wim Thanks for the advice. I've been curious what extra black offers than just "continuously linting" while vim'ing, which is what I'm doing right now?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe break it up into multiple imports

```
from a.b import c
from c.d import e
....etc
```

Comment: This approach is wrong! An `import` statement treats its operand as identifiers, meaning the module bound to `c` on the first line is *not* used as the base for the import on the second line. This approach is unsuitable to shorten an import from a deeply nested import.

Answer (score 0):

You can do line continuation in python using the '\' character.

```
import lib.very_long_lib_name.very_long_util_name\
    .very_long_tool_module_name as module_name
```

would work. It would even let you indent the next line so that linter does not complain of underindent.

Answer (score 0):

For a different take on this... I believe the following should work:

```
import importlib

func = importlib.import_module(
   'a.very.very.very.very.'
   'very.very.very.very.very.'
   'very.very.very.long.path.'
   'to.module'
).func
```