# Shorten long module name in import statement

Tags: python, python-import

I need to import a module that has a very long name:

```
from some_package.some_module.first_submodule.second_submodule import (
    SomeClass
)
```

in my example the full reference `some_package.some_module.first_submodule.second_submodule` is too long for my formatter and linter (I currently limit line-length to 100 characters).

I know that I can break up the line like this:

```
from some_package.some_module.first_submodule.\
    second_submodule import SomeClass
```

but my formatter undoes this (and I dislike it).

I have seen [Long imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273847/long-imports-in-python) but unfortunately it does not address my issue.

any ideas how i can import from this module without exceeding my maximal line length?